# Как в python сохранять записанные данные в файл сразу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

Насколько я знаю, при записи текста в файл .txt, данные будут записаны в файл после выполнения программы, при выполнении кода `file.close()`

Как сохранять записанные данные в файл сразу после записи ? Или мне придётся каждый раз открывать и закрывать файл для сохранения записи в нём ?

Comment: И всё же я бы полагался только на закрытие файла. Сброс буфера вещь хорошая, но не панацея, мне кажется. А вообще хорошо бы обозначить - что за задача перед вами стоит. Может лучше использовать для таких целей БД, например.

Comment: @CrazyElf, задача записывать определённые строки в файл, и после каждой записи, нужно сохранять результат, что бы если программа упадёт, то результат сохранился в файле. БД не подходит, прога маленькая, особого смысла не вижу.

Comment: @CrazyElf, просто что лучше, сбросить данные из буфера, или каждый раз закрывать и открывать файл по новой ? Мне кажется открытие и закрытие файла дольше будет.

Comment: Ну смотря сколько данных и как часто вы пишете. На мой взгляд открывать и закрывать файл просто правильнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документация - великая вещь! ;)

Инициирует сброс данных из буфера в файл.

> file.flush()

Ввиду того, что вывод в файл буферизируется, данные, записанные при помощи `file.write()` и `file.writelines()` в файловую систему могут попасть не сразу. Для форсирования сброса содержимого можно использовать данный метод, а можно дождаться отработки `file.close()`

Comment: Tatarintsev, документация великая вещь, только её ещё найти нужно. Гуглил "работа с файлами python", но про flush ничего не нашёл. Спасибо за ваш ответ, это то что нужно !

Answer (score 1):

Возможно я не совсем верно понял вопрос. Но предположу, что вам поможет `with`

```py
with open("hello.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write('Hello')
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то. По сути with as это тоже самое открытие и закрытие файла.